# How do I route in to a dynamic network (pptp client)?

Tags: routing

I have a Centos 6 server. It is acting as a pptp server.

My home router is dialing a pptp connection to the server as a client, and gets an IP.

Communication between them is fine, but I want the server to be able to access the network behind the client router. It's quite a large network, with many subnets.

The problem is I cant find a way to permanently route all 172.16.0.0/16 destinations through the client IP which in this case is 172.16.10.2 (the server is 172.16.10.1).

Since the PPTP connection is dynamic it doesnt have an interface that I can set its routing to.

How do I go about doing this?